# OpenCV Trackbar - show double value instead of int

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using `createTrackbar(const string& trackbarname, const string& winname, int* value, int count, TrackbarCallback onChange=0, void* userdata=0)` in openCV to get an input value, which needs to be a double in the range between 0 and 1. I can easily calculate the needed value from the trackbar position, but obviously the GUI only shows the int-value for the slider, which is a little bit irritating.

Is there any way to change the value the trackbar shows? I can't find any information about this in the documentation or tutorials...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, there is not.** Unfortunately, the way the trackbar is implemented (with or without Qt) it does not support that.

Comment: Do you now it it is possible to get the trackbar to stop showing any value?

Comment: I'm afraid it is not possible either. The trackbar, as many other features in opencv_highgui, is quite poor in terms of configuration. The OpenCV guys did a great job including these features, but OpenCV is not intended to be a toolkit for creating UIs, not even the simpler ones. HOWEVER: take a look to OpenCV 3.0.0 (to be released). It includes quite fancier, Matlab-ish UI features.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is not possibility to pass double or other floating point value but still if you are okay let's say with 0.001 precision you can create a trackbar with max value 1000 and then simply treat its value as a double betwen 0 and 1 by dividing trackbar value by max value.

Comment: I'm doing this right now and I'm displaying the current value in the corner of my image Mat, but it would be a lot more comfortable and less irritating if the trackbar would already show the actual value. But unfortunately, as KeillRandor stated above, this is not possible...

Answer (score 0):

Like already stated, this is not possible. 
Here is a little wrapper which calculates double values for you conveniently:

```
class DoubleTrack{
public:

    int int_value = 0;
    double precision;
    void(*user_callback)(double);

    void setup(const std::string& field_name, const std::string& window_name, void(*function)(double), double max_value, double default_value = 0, unsigned precision = 100){
            int_value = default_value * precision;
            createTrackbar(field_name, window_name, &int_value, max_value * precision, DoubleTrack::callback, this);
            user_callback = function;
            this->precision = precision;
    }

    static void callback(int, void* object){
        DoubleTrack* pObject = static_cast<DoubleTrack*>(object);
        pObject->user_callback(pObject->int_value / pObject->precision);
    }

};

static void test(double value){
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}

DoubleTrack().setup("field_name", "window_name", test, 4.5);
```

Comment: segfaults and crashes